# What are the differences between using routes (direction service) and using polyline with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes, polyline

I read in the documentation that using polyline, I just have a straight line between two points. And if I use Routes (direction service), I don't have the straight line, but a real route between this two places (points).

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly.  Polyline means you give a list (array) of points; the polyline follows those points (with a straight line from one point to the next).
If you only give the start and end point, then yes, it will be a straight line (still following the curve of the earth).

You can request a route, read the waypoints of the route and make (draw) a polyline that follows the exact route.

The only reason you would do this, is because you have much more control over the polyline than over the standard route that Google draws.

Example: with a polyline, you can easily set onClick events on that polyline; it's a harder to do this with the standard route

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you recommend use Polyline instead of standard route?

Comment: I would recommend you start with the standard route display.  Until you feel you don't have enough control over it, then you're kind of obliged to use the polyline

Comment: This is very old answer, but still very relevant today. By the way, is there any limit on the number of coordinates we pass in directions api today? I see some places that 23 is the maximum coordinates will be served in direction API.